# cp: not writing through dangling symlink '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so'

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, caffe, ubuntu-16.04, pycaffe

I am facing this issue, Could you please give me some hints how to solve this:

```
$sudo cp ~/anaconda2/lib/libhdf5* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
cp: not writing through dangling symlink '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5.so'
cp: not writing through dangling symlink '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_hl.so'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see that question is a bit outdated, but anyway:

A *dangling symlink* is, actually, broken symlink, which points to nowhere.
So in such situation the one have to check destination path (maybe it's moved somewhere) or use cp's parameter `--remove-destination`.

from `man cp` page:

```
--remove-destination
    remove  each existing destination file before attempting to open
    it (contrast with --force)
```